# Do Cardano NFTs contain stable content?

Tags: plutus, nft

In our company we discuss the Twitter post of the Signal founder: https://moxie.org/2022/01/07/web3-first-impressions.html. One critique is, that the NFTs don't contain the hash of data (jpg, ...) but a link to a centralized page that is outside of the control of the blockchain and whose content can change.

How does it work for Cardano or CNFT.io for example. Do they contain the hash of the image or a Link to IPFS or something?

When I look at an NFT on CNFT.io I don't find a hash that works with https://explorer.cardano.org/ to check it myself.

Thanks in advance for hints!

Comment: Ah, using https://cardanoscan.io/ with the "POLICY ID" of a token on cnft.io I can find the token on the chain. E.g. https://cardanoscan.io/token/8c06b3c611ec9bc9037c76a9e2cf270c7a147341e6daffeda614cdd5426f726733323838. So that part is answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the metadata in a Cardano NFT is not set in stone. As in you can decide what it contains. Using a reference to an ipfs storage location is one convenient way to add the actual content of the NFT.

You can read more about the technical process of minting NFT's here:
https://developers.cardano.org/docs/native-tokens/minting-nfts/

There's also an interesting discussion on having a metadata standard going on in this CIP (Cardano improvement proposal):
https://github.com/cardano-foundation/CIPs/pull/85

If you want to see the metadata of a specific NFT you should be able to see it on the marketplace you're using. Personally I've found https://pool.pm/tokens very useful for finding tokens and their metadata.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Seeing the NFTs at https://pool.pm/tokens and their metadata with the IPFS link was very useful!